# r Kohonen map - How to find position of one dataset?

Tags: r, self-organizing-maps

I have a dataframe df with my data of interest

I rescale with

```
df.sc <- scale(df)
```

and make my Kohonen map with

```
df.grid <- somgrid(15, 10, "hexagonal")
df.som <- som(df.sc, rlen=700, grid = df.grid)
```

That works fine and I get a nice map.

Now I have an extra datapoint

```
extra.sc <- as.matrix(-0.29985191, -0.35905786, -0.260923297, -0.2415673150,
 -0.259426676, -0.330404078)
```

It is scaled exactly the same way as df.sc

Now I want to see the position of the unit in the kohonen map given the df.som for the extra.sc

```
map(df.som,extra.sc)
```

does not give me what I want.

How can I determine the position of extra.sc within df.som? And preferentially also how I can mark it on the map

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you defined your new data incorrectly, i.e. they did not have similar dimension with that of the training data. Check the output of `extra.sc` using parenthesis `(extra.sc)`. I recommend that you provide the number of rows and columns to the definition of `extra.sc` using `matrix()` and `c()` function instead of `as.matrix()`. For example:

```
extra.sc <- matrix(c(0.29985191, -0.35905786, -0.260923297, -0.2415673150, -0.259426676, -0.330404078), nrow = 1, ncol = 6)`
```

and observe the result:

`(extra.sc)`

It is one row and six columns. If you do not provide the shape of your data, then R will regard them as one column and six rows.

```
extra.sc <- matrix(c(-0.29985191, -0.35905786, -0.260923297, -0.2415673150, -0.259426676, -0.330404078))

(extra.sc)
```